# How Hyperledger Fabric roll back data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I read documents about the way Hyperledger Fabric network accepts data to write to the ledger. It's done by endorser peers.
But this is another case, I have a scenario like multiple times call PutState.

```
// 1. Update User 
err = stub.PutState(userKey, updateUser)
if err != nil {
    return nil, Response.Error
}
// 2. Update Product
err = stub.PutState(productKey, updateProduct)
if err != nil {
    return nil, Response.Error
}
```

It pretty stranges that if the second call (**update product**) failed, but the first call (**update user**) successful. The **user data** still appear in the ledger but it shouldn't. I have two questions:

1. *Can anyone explain to me or give me any documents related to the rollback in this case?*
2. *How I can solve this problem to make a true rollback?*

Fabric version 1.4

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the result that you are getting. You are calling `PutState` two times and first call is independent of second call hence it is putting the data to ledger. If the first call fails then second call won't execute because of the `return` statement in `if err` condition in first call but not vice-versa.

Comment: I didn't say the first call failed?

Answer (score 1):

A proposal sent from Client to Peer might call ledger's methods multiple times. Normally, a successful chaincode invocation should reach `return shim.Success(nil)` [chaincode example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/chaincode_example02.go)

When you invoke chaincode stub's methods (`PutState`, `GetState`,...), the chaincode service will send a message to the stream which is already connected to the Peer - Endorser to **try to interact** with the ledger. You can take a look at the Fabric's source code [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/b17b6dd8e2b9940f12506942c09cf6dc85a94440/core/chaincode/handler.go#L174) - where the Endorser handle event from chaincode service.

If your first call success, the Peer response to the chaincode service with no error. This does not mean that the ledger is updated. A transaction is only successful while it is committed to a block.

When the second call is failed, the invocation will end with the error. The Peer will provide an error response to the caller. If the caller keeps sending that transaction to the Orderer, the Peer - Submitter still rejects it => No data is really updated => Nothing need to rollback

I think you should carefully read [the transaction flow document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html?highlight=transaction%20flow)

In your case, let's try to `return shim.Error(err.Error())` when an error is triggered

Comment: I knew everything you said, that's why I said it's pretty strange that data appeared in the ledger

Comment: Sorry no, but I already return a Success or Error peer.Response. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please describe more about your network (elements, version, which SDK you've used for the Client), and the source code of the smart contract?

Comment: Btw, thanks for your help. I will check my code again, I might have a latent bug. :/

Comment: Well, so I hope you can share the reason and solution after solving the problem. I'm also curious about this :)

Comment: I hope so. Thank you